# Can I figure out skin tone or body temperature using kinect?

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

Is there any way that I can figure out skin tone or body temperature using kinect?

Comment: if you are from the marketing department, yes you can, otherwise the science is pretty clear about that: nope.

Comment: While I don't believe the kinect to be possible of doing this, I don't think science has anything to say here - it's plenty possible, with just the right equipment.

Answer (score 4):

The kinect does have an infrared camera that it uses in conjunction with an IR projector to capture the depth picture, however, the IR camera is only sensitive at near-infrared frequencies (wavelength of ~1 micron). 'Thermal' infrared is typically at a much longer wavelength - 1 to 300 microns, and these cameras are not sensitive to it. There's a reason thermal imaging cameras are so very expensive, unfortunately.

Here's some discussion that might be helpful to you

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6869/what-is-the-difference-between-thermal-and-infrared-imaging