# Is it possible to detect heat signatures using Kinect

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

Hi since kinect has a infrared camera which theoretically enables thermal imaging. Is it possible to detect specific heat signatures in a human body? Are there any API DOCS that can be useful to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in order to enable thermal imaging, you need an infrared camera with a wavelength that is far outside the Kinect's range. So no, no heat signatures with Kinect.

More info here:

[Can I figure out skin tone or body temperature using kinect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889357/can-i-figure-out-skin-tone-or-body-temperature-using-kinect)

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6869/what-is-the-difference-between-thermal-and-infrared-imaging

http://answers.ros.org/question/61076/kinect-thermal-imaging/